# All possible summation

Tags: algorithm, matrix, combinations

I have two matrices:

```
A=[1 2 3];
B=[4 5 6];
```

The all possible combinations of their summation is

```
[1+4 1+5 1+6; 2+4 2+5 2+6;3+4 3+5 3+6]
```

Now instead of 1*3 my matrix dimension is 1*n. And instead of two I have N number of them.

How can I find their all possible combinations of summation matrix?

Comment: (I advise against using characters only differentiated by capitalization (or alphabet) in one context without need, especially if what they are denoting is independent. At the very least, it complicates audible communication.) Use recursion on the `matrices`: `if (list empty) append prefix to result and return; for ( every element e in list.head ) tackOn(prefix + e, list.tail);`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the arrays:

```
for ( every element a in A ) {
    for ( every element b in B ) {
        consider s = a + b 
        use s
    }
}
```

If the expected result is a 2D array containing the result for every sum, here is a **JavaScript implementation**:

```
var A = [1,2,3,10];
var B = [4,5,6];

var M = new Array(A.length);
for ( var i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++ ) {
    M[i] = new Array(B.length);
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < B.length ; j++ ) {        
        M[i][j] = A[i] + B[j];
    }        
}

for ( var i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++ ) {
    var line = '';
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < B.length ; j++ ) {
        line += M[i][j]+'  ';
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

Result:

```
5  6  7  
6  7  8  
7  8  9  
14  15  16
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you have M arrays each with N elements and want to find all possible combinations, you want to look at the [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) method.

You could implement this as such:

1. Keep an array (I) of indices into the N vectors, initially set to 0
2. At each step, add one to the first element of this index array
3. Now if this first element modulo n is 0, set this element to 0 and move to the next element in the array and increment it
4. Repeat step 3 for the current element
5. If you exceed the last element, then you are done
6. If not, print the current configuration and return to the first position in I

AN illustration of how this works for two arrays with two elements is:

1. [0 0] -> print
2. +1  -> [1 0] -> print
3. +1 ->  [2 0] (%2) -> [0 1] -> print
4. +1 ->  [1 1]  -> print
5. +1 -> [2 1] (%2) -> [0 2] (%2) -> [0 0] -> exit

You could do this in Python like so

```
def printSol(As, I):
    print I, '-->',
    for p in range(len(As)):
        print As[p][I[p]],
    print

def main():

    As = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]

    n = len(As[0])
    I = [0] * n
    pos = 0

    printSol(As, I)

    while True:
        I[pos] += 1

        while I[pos] % n == 0:
            I[pos] = 0
            pos += 1
            if pos >= len(I):
                return
            I[pos] += 1
        pos = 0

        printSol(As, I)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Which generates all possible 27 combinations:

```
[0, 0, 0] --> 1 4 7
[1, 0, 0] --> 2 4 7
[2, 0, 0] --> 3 4 7
[0, 1, 0] --> 1 5 7
[1, 1, 0] --> 2 5 7
[2, 1, 0] --> 3 5 7
[0, 2, 0] --> 1 6 7
[1, 2, 0] --> 2 6 7
[2, 2, 0] --> 3 6 7
[0, 0, 1] --> 1 4 8
[1, 0, 1] --> 2 4 8
[2, 0, 1] --> 3 4 8
[0, 1, 1] --> 1 5 8
[1, 1, 1] --> 2 5 8
[2, 1, 1] --> 3 5 8
[0, 2, 1] --> 1 6 8
[1, 2, 1] --> 2 6 8
[2, 2, 1] --> 3 6 8
[0, 0, 2] --> 1 4 9
[1, 0, 2] --> 2 4 9
[2, 0, 2] --> 3 4 9
[0, 1, 2] --> 1 5 9
[1, 1, 2] --> 2 5 9
[2, 1, 2] --> 3 5 9
[0, 2, 2] --> 1 6 9
[1, 2, 2] --> 2 6 9
[2, 2, 2] --> 3 6 9
```